# QuickBlox - How to get json responses

Tags: quickblox

I'm using Quickblox and aparently my responses are XMLs. I need to know how to receive JSon responses.
Is there any property I need to set?

PS: I use iOS SDK

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now XML format is supported in iOS SDK.
We are going to move to JSON in next release.

But, could you explain why do you need this. This is just raw data, end users work with objects, not raw xml/json data.

Comment: Thanks Igor! In fact I just wanted to know if this was possible, so that responses processing could be faster, considering I'm going to exchange a big amount of data, probably.